# Bad indentation of a mapping entry in Serverless AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm trying to upload a simple Lambda to Serverless however I keep getting :

```
bad indentation of a mapping entry in ...
            - schedule:
                      ^
```

The code :

**serverless.yml**

```
service: serverlesslambda
functions:
  changeWeeklyStarterStatus:
    handler:
      handler.changeWeeklyStarterStatus      
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(0 0 0 ? * SUN *)
```

**handler.js:**

```
"use strict";

module.exports.changeWeeklyStarterStatus = async event => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        input: event
      },
      null,
      2
    )
  };
};
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here for an example - https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/openwhisk-node-scheduled-cron/serverless.yml

You can either give cron expression or rate not both. see here for details : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to back indent the `schedule`. And yes you can't have both `rates` and `cron`. Rate is useful to schedule events on a fixed interval (for e.g every hour). Cron is for Cron expressions.

```
service: serverlesslambda
functions:
    changeWeeklyStarterStatus:
    handler:
        handler.changeWeeklyStarterStatus      
        schedule: cron(0 0 0 ? * SUN *)
```